# Chef used for deploying service into Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Irrespective of how Cloud Foundry is deployed?  This is the impression we get looking at the guides such as [this one](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-collaboration/vcap-services/wiki/How-to-add-a-system-service-to-Cloud-Foundry---step-by-step-guide) and the contents of the `.../cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/cookbooks` directory in a fresh cloudfoundry install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Chef is used extensively for creating VCAP deployments.

Comment: My question was specifically whether it was always Chef.  In the mean time my understanding is that if your Cloud Foundry deployment is NOT with BOSH then deployment of services into BOSH is via Chef.  If you are deploying services into a Cloud Foundry release for BOSH, then sevices are added via BOSH "manifests" - jobs, packages.  Sound right?

Comment: that's about right - you can use dev_setup which are Chef scripts, of you can use BOSH.